# How to Send POST data to Laravel in IE 8+ CORS (with XDomainRequest)

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

```
 xdr = new XDomainRequest(); // Creates a new XDR object.
        xdr.timeout = 3000;//Set the timeout time to 3 second.
        xdr.onload = function(){
            try {
                var res = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
                callback(res)
              } catch(e) {
                console.log("Json format");
                //throw 'Invalid JSON: ' + xdr.responseText;
              }
        };
        xdr.onerror = function(){
            console.log("can't get data from server")
            $('#ServerMessage').show();
        };
        xdr.ontimeout = function () {
            $('#ServerMessage').show();
        };
        xdr.open(method,this.url); // Creates a cross-domain connection with our target server using GET method.
        xdr.send(JSON.stringify(object)); //Send string data to server
```

I've been able to make a simple POST request, but haven't been able to add POST data to it.

Comment: what is the value of `method` and `object`? if method is POST (assumption as you don't show what it is) what does your current code actually send? (developer tools network tab will show the request) - also, check developer tools console for any errors you may be getting

Comment: No error, but not return data from server. method POST, object = {name: "text"}. Error only Internet Explorer

Comment: `No error` ... `Error only` ... huh? also you've not addressed the following: what does your code actually send - surely you can see that in the developer tools network tab (unless IE8 doesn't have one of those of course)